# 'GO' button submits form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created an hybrid app using Angular and Ionic, but when I fill in my form and press the *GO* button or the arrow button on Android it submits my form even though it's not valid yet. I've tried to detect the keypress and `return:false;` but it still submits it.

```
    <form novalidate name="questionForm" id="questionForm" ng-submit="submit()">
        <input name="question" ng-model="form.question" ng-minlength="10" required autofocus/>
        <div id="answers">
<input ng-model="choice.choice" placeholder="Voeg antwoord toe" required ng-keypress="disableGo()" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="questionForm.$invalid" class="circle-btn btn-send ion-ios-paperplane"></button>
    </form>
```

Keypress function:

```
    $scope.disableGo = function () {
        var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if ((code == 13) || (code == 10)) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `type='button'` instead of `submit`

You do not need `disableGo`

Try this:

```html
<form novalidate name="questionForm" id="questionForm">
  <input name="question" ng-model="form.question" ng-minlength="10" required autofocus/>
  <div id="answers">
    <input ng-model="choice.choice" placeholder="Voeg antwoord toe" required ng-keypress="disableGo()" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" ng-disabled="questionForm.$invalid" class="circle-btn btn-send ion-ios-paperplane" ng-click="submit()"></button>
</form>
```

Use `ng-click` on `button` instead of `ng-submit`

Comment: Oh right, that worked. Thanks. I'll accept your answer in 5 min

Answer (score 1):

Add type to your button as button may help you

```
  <button type="button"></button>
```

Comment: Then my form won't be submitted when I press my submit button. Angular uses `ng-submit`so it looks for a `type=submit`button

Answer (score 1):

you can check this

add a function in controller:

```
$scope.canSubmit = function () {
        return ($scope.questionForm.$dirty && $scope.questionForm.$invalid) || $scope.questionForm.$pristine
};
```

in html: use `type="button"`

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="canSubmit()" class="circle-btn btn-send ion-ios-paperplane"></button>
```